# How to Export a BoxCutter mesh into a renderer?

Tags: mesh, export

Blender beginner here.

I'm playing with MasterXeon1001's amazing BoxCutter add-on in Blender2.8, and I'm getting undesired results when I try exporting my cut-up model into Octane (see image).

Is there a certain process that I need to do while exporting for the exported object to look the way it does in Blender?  I've tried exporting as both an OBJ and an FBX, but have similar results.

Thanks in advance!

[image: Blender left, Octane right]

[image]

Comment: What did you try so far? How did you export your model? Format? Export parameters?  You can add the missing information to your question by using the [edit link](https://blender.stackexchange.com/posts/137514/edit) below it.

Comment: Updated the post to reflect this.  I only tried exporting as an OBJ and an FBX.  Neither have worked.

Comment: Export parameters still missing...

Comment: Sorry!  Once again, im a newbie in both Blender and the world of 3D.  Bare with me.  I've included the parameters in a new photo in the post

Comment: Box cutter and similar addons are boolean based. Boolean operations are (as you can see) very bad workflow in Blender. You problem lies not in export, it comes from unclean modelling techniques.

Comment: So there is no way to freeze the geometry (as bad and dense as it is) to open it up in a new program?

Comment: Bumping this up, as I still have not received an answer

Comment: Givent that this is a paid addon, it seems to me that you should post this question to the developer.

Comment: Import to sustance painter and then export remember Apply triangulation

Answer (score 0):

I have found a solution. Modus Destructive not Non destructive. Export as .stl file.

Comment: Note: In boxcutter, you can work non-destructively for a while, and when you're satisfied, you can apply the modifier stack to get a final mesh.